# Want to login to Router with android application

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, jackson

I'm just starting to develop android application and want to try to connect to my router. Wrote application using Jackson, but get stuck with json request for login to the router. IP of my router is 192.168.1.1 and username and password should be taken from EditText fields.
                                                                              android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

There is json string for login:

> { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [ "00000000000000000000000000000000", "session",
>    "login", { "username": "root", "password": "admin01"  } ] }

This is my RestRequest.java

```
public class RestRequest {

private static final String TAG = JacksonUtil.class.getSimpleName();
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

//Constructor with no parameter
public RestRequest(){

}

public String makeWebServiceCall(String url, int requestmethod){
    return this.makeWebServiceCall(url, requestmethod, null);
}

public String makeWebServiceCall(String urladdress, int requestmethod, HashMap<String, String> params){

    URL url;
    String responce = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(urladdress);

        HttpURLConnection urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlconnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
        urlconnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlconnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);

        if(requestmethod == POST){
            urlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        }else if(requestmethod == GET){
            urlconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }

        if(params != null){
            OutputStream outputstream = urlconnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream, "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.append("&");

                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            bufferedWriter.write(result.toString());

            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputstream.close();
        }

        int responceCode = urlconnection.getResponseCode();

        if(responceCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlconnection.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                responce += line;
            }
        }else {
            responce = "";
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException parsing to json", e);
    }

    return response;
}
```

> Edited my LoginActivity.java 
>   Can anyone to look at this activity and tell what I'm doing wrong

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String page_url = "http://192.168.1.1/ubus";

@Bind(R.id.user_name_edit_text)
TextView user_name;

@Bind(R.id.user_password_edit_text)
TextView user_password;

@Bind(R.id.login_button)
Button login_button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
ButterKnife.bind(this);

login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String url = page_url;
        String username = getUserName();
        String password = getPassword();

        TryToLogin tryToLogin = new TryToLogin();
        tryToLogin.execute(url, username, password);
    }
});


class TryToLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(page_url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        connection.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public String getUserName() {
    String username = user_name.getText().toString();
    return username;
}

private String getPassword() {
    String password = user_password.getText().toString();
    return password;
}
```

Comment: you are making network call on main ui thread. put makeWebServiceCall() code off the UI thread. You can use async task for this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make network calls using the main thread in Android - this is by design to ensure the UI thread remains responsive and does not wait. You need to perform this call in an AsyncThread or normal Thread